# Ordering Array with model

Tags: php, arrays

I need to order an array with a model but i don't know if it's possible in PHP, could someone tell me in which direction, function can i look for?

MY ARRAY :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => jeudi-1
            [title] => Jeudi-1
            [id] => 3182
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => vendredi-1
            [title] => Vendredi-1
            [id] => 3183
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => lundi-5
            [title] => Lundi-5
            [id] => 3448
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => mardi-5
            [title] => Mardi-5
            [id] => 3449
        )

)
```

MY ORDER MODEL

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'lundi-5',
    [1] => 'mardi-5',
    [2] => 'jeudi-1',
    [3] => 'vendredi-1'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first flip the keys with the values in your order array, using [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php):

```
$swap_order = array_flip($order);
```

then you can get your result using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like this:

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($swap_order) {
    return $swap_order[$a["name"]] - $swap_order[$b["name"]];
});
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/631041).